# How do I select a menu item via AT command on Quectel M26 chip?

Tags: quectel

I am trying to use the SIM Menu using the STK of Quectel M26 and I am having trouble traversing the menu via AT command with their STK.

Inserting the SIM card will result to a +STKPCI response:

```
+CPIN: READY

Call Ready

+STKPCI: 0,"D03F810301250082028182850A476C6F6265204C6F61648F0D01526567756C6172204C6F61648F0A02496E76656E746F72798F0D034C6F616420486F746C696E65"
```

parsing this will result to this:

```
D0 // pro-active command
3F // length
81 03 012500 // command details
82 02 8182 // device identity
85 0A 476C6F6265204C6F6164 // Globe Load
8F 0D 01 526567756C6172204C6F6164 // Regular Load
8F 0A 02 496E76656E746F7279 // Inventory
8F 0D 03 4C6F616420486F746C696E65 // Load Hotline
```

As per Quectel document (GSM_STK_ATC_V1.1), this is how to go back one menu:

```
AT+STKTR="810301230082028281830111"

81 03 012300 // command details (replacing 24 with 23)
82 02 8281 // device identity
83 01 11 // go back one step
```

And to go back is to use this command:

```
AT+STKTR="810301230082028281830110"

81 03 012300 // command details
82 02 8281 // device identity
83 01 10 // back to main
```

Issuing these will result to an "OK", but since I still can't go through other options I am not able to test it fully

Now, to my issue, I can't figure out how to select an item. I already tried this but it only responded to an "OK" and nothing else

I tried selecting it by item ID:

`AT+STKTR="8103012300820281828301008D0102"`

```
81 03 012300 // command details
82 02 8182 // device identity
83 01 00 // get input
8D 01 02 // selecting Inventory by item ID
```

I tried selecting with the text:

```
AT+STKTR="8103012300820281828301008D09496E76656E746F7279"

81 03 012300 // command details
82 02 8182 // device identity
83 01 00 // get input
8D 09 496E76656E746F7279 // selecting Inventory by text
```

I also tried selecting it with both:

```
AT+STKTR="8103012300820281828301008D09496E76656E746F7279"

81 03 012300 // command details
82 02 8182 // device identity
83 01 00 // get input
8D 0A 02496E76656E746F7279 // selecting Inventory by ID & text
```

Also tried to use envelope command

```
AT+STKENV="D30782028182900101"

D3 // menu selection
07 // length
82 02 8182 // // device identity
90 01 02 // selecting Inventory
```

However, none of those has any other response.

So my question is how do I select a menu item via AT command on Quectel M26 chip?